# Solr facet exclude words from output

Tags: solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise, facet, faceted-search

Below is my Solr request

`localhost:8983/solr/keyspace.table/select?q=*:*&fq=date:[2016-03-01T00:00:00Z TO 2016-03-01T00:59:00Z]&rows=0&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=title`

This gives me output like

```
"facet_counts": {
"facet_queries": {},
"facet_fields": {
  "title": [
    "on",
    24,
    "demand",
    6,
    "gold",
    6,
    "rebounds",
    6,
    "silver",
    6,
    "slips",
    6,
    "subdued",
    6,
    "abuse",
    3,
    "back",
    3,
    "at",
    2,
    .
    .
```

I want to remove some words from this, for e.g. I want to exclude `on` and `at` from the output. There could be many words like this, which I would like to supply to solr, which it should exclude. Is there any way to do this?

On searching, I found and tried something like `fq={!tag=title}title:"on"` but that did not work, it still returned same output.

Also, by default it returns only 100 words and their count. I want upto 1000 or 2000 words, can we supply the number of words we want as output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a separate field that only have the tokens you want to facet on. You can do this by applying a [StopFilter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.StopFilterFactory) - which you can configure with all the values you want removed. You want to do this at index time, so a re-index will be necessary after adding it to the list of filters.

You can exclude documents from the result by using `fq` which match the documents that doesn't contain the field (using `-term` or NOT as the boolean operator).

Answer (score 2):

As per the number of results check: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.limit

As per the words you want to exclude you need to go into Solr manual, the exact version you're using, and look for 'stop words' and the different possibilities Solr gives you to achieve what you want.

Sorry I can't be of further help.

Comment: Thanks, the facet.limit thing helped.